How do I keep files unique to a git subtree? (Shopify version control)
The page on Shopify's version control best practices recommends (here) using git subtrees to separate source code and compiled code, but they do not provide practical examples. As I understand it, I want something like this:
/production/assets/main.css
/production/layout/theme.liquid
/src/main.scss
.gitignore

If I use .gitignore to ignore /production/assets/main.css then the compiled file stays out of main. 
I can then run git subtree split --prefix=production --annotate='[subtree] ' --branch production --rejoin to create a production branch which looks like this:
/assets/main.css
/layout/theme.liquid

Now my source files are excluded  and my compiled file is no longer ignored, so it can be committed.  (This is desirable because Shopify needs to be able to pull this file.)
However, my problem arises when I want to merge any changes from production back into main. If I run git subtree merge --prefix=production --squash production then I get any changes that Shopify has committed to that branch  but I also now have the compiled file /production/assets/main.css committed to main. 
How can I separate source code from compiled code using git subtree while allowing me to merge changes made to the production branch?
